# -gate meaning scandal

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, suffixes

Does the suffix -gate necessarily refer to a political scandal? Can it refer to a scandal involving large businesses but no government officials?

Could **burgergate** refer to a scandal in which a company passed horse meat off as beef for burgers?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: See also [Why do we use the suffix “‑gate” when referring to a scandal?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36800/why-do-we-use-the-suffix-gate-when-referring-to-a-scandal) on ELU. Also ['-gate' as a suffix to coin words related to scandals and corruption cases](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/144673/gate-as-a-suffix-to-coin-words-related-to-scandals-and-corruption-cases) and [-gate, and gamergate](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/234558/gate-and-gamergate), and probably others.

Answer (score 1):

This started as a reference to the [Watergate scandal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watergate_scandal), so named because it happened in the Watergate Hotel. And as with all references there are no real formal rules in place that tell you when it is aplicable and when it is not. So going by just the [dictionary definition](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/watergate?s=t) it is used reasonably often to describe any abuse of power.

But note that this is very informal and in my opinion these days overused for *any* scandal, down to the level of who-ate-the-cookiesgate.